# printing image paths from the dataloader in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, facial-identification

I am trying to learn One-shot learning with pytorch. I am experimenting with this [Siamese Network in Pytorch example](https://github.com/harveyslash/Facial-Similarity-with-Siamese-Networks-in-Pytorch/blob/master/Siamese-networks-medium.ipynb). Using that notebook as a guide, I simply would like to print out the image file paths for each pair of images, in addition to the dissimilarity scores.

From what I've been reading, it looks like I need to make some alterations to the dataloader in order to achieve this, as indicated [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/dataloader-filenames-in-each-batch/4212/2).

I do not have much experience yet in all of this. I would appreciate some guidance. I imported the altered dataloader [(as in this gist)](https://gist.github.com/andrewjong/6b02ff237533b3b2c554701fb53d5c4d) into my code.

The altered dataloader:

```
import torch
from torchvision import datasets

class ImageFolderWithPaths(datasets.ImageFolder):
    """Custom dataset that includes image file paths. Extends
    torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder
    """

    # override the __getitem__ method. this is the method that dataloader calls
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # this is what ImageFolder normally returns 
        original_tuple = super(ImageFolderWithPaths, self).__getitem__(index)
        # the image file path
        path = self.imgs[index][0]
        # make a new tuple that includes original and the path
        tuple_with_path = (original_tuple + (path,))
        return tuple_with_path
```

and the example usage:

```
data_dir = "your/data_dir/here"
dataset = ImageFolderWithPaths(data_dir) # our custom dataset
dataloader = torch.utils.DataLoader(dataset)

# iterate over data
for inputs, labels, paths in dataloader:
    # use the above variables freely
    print(inputs, labels, paths)
```

my code:

```
from pytorch_image_folder_with_file_paths import ImageFolderWithPaths

folder_dataset_test = dset.ImageFolder(root=Config.testing_dir)
siamese_dataset = SiameseNetworkDataset(imageFolderDataset=folder_dataset_test,
                                        transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((100,100)),
                                                                      transforms.ToTensor()
                                                                      ])
                                       ,should_invert=False)

test_dataloader = DataLoader(siamese_dataset,num_workers=6,batch_size=1,shuffle=True)

dataiter = iter(test_dataloader)
x0,_,_ = next(dataiter)

for i in range(10):
    _,x1,label2 = next(dataiter)

    concatenated = torch.cat((x0,x1),0)

    output1,output2 = net(Variable(x0).cuda(),Variable(x1).cuda())
    euclidean_distance = F.pairwise_distance(output1, output2)
    imshow(torchvision.utils.make_grid(concatenated),'Dissimilarity: {:.2f}'.format(euclidean_distance.item()))

for inputs, labels, paths in test_dataloader:
    print(inputs, labels, paths)
```

I get the paired images with the dissimilarity score, but I don't get the paths; I get

```
tensor([[[[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
          ...,
          [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]]]]) tensor([[[[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
          ...,
```

...etc.

Thanks

Comment: You are not using `ImageFolderWithPaths` in your code anywhere, just importing it.

Comment: Right, right. So... I'd use here `siamese_dataset = SiameseNetworkDataset(imageFolderDataset ` then?

Comment: Yeah, I tested the above code with `SiameseNetworkDataset(imageFolderDataset)` and it's working perfectly, returning paths also.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Anubhav Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5810950/anubhav-singh) for sorting me out.

This works:

```
from pytorch_image_folder_with_file_paths import ImageFolderWithPaths

folder_dataset_test = ImageFolderWithPaths(root=Config.testing_dir)
siamese_dataset = SiameseNetworkDataset(imageFolderDataset=folder_dataset_test,
                                        transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((100,100)),
                                                                      transforms.ToTensor()
                                                                      ])
                                       ,should_invert=False)

test_dataloader = DataLoader(siamese_dataset,num_workers=6,batch_size=1,shuffle=True)

dataiter = iter(test_dataloader)
x0,_,_ = next(dataiter)

for i in range(10):
    _,x1,label2 = next(dataiter)

    concatenated = torch.cat((x0,x1),0)

    output1,output2 = net(Variable(x0).cuda(),Variable(x1).cuda())
    euclidean_distance = F.pairwise_distance(output1, output2)
    imshow(torchvision.utils.make_grid(concatenated),'Dissimilarity: {:.2f}'.format(euclidean_distance.item()))

for paths in folder_dataset_test:
    # use the above variables freely
    print(paths)
```

Incidentally, I'm working in Google Colab which doesn't allow me to edit files directly, so for the dataloader, I made a new cell and used `%%writefile` to get it into my notebook:

```
%%writefile pytorch_image_folder_with_file_paths.py

import torch
import torchvision.datasets as dset

class ImageFolderWithPaths(dset.ImageFolder):
    """Custom dataset that includes image file paths. Extends
    torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder
    """

    # override the __getitem__ method. this is the method that dataloader calls
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # this is what ImageFolder normally returns 
        original_tuple = super(ImageFolderWithPaths, self).__getitem__(index)
        # the image file path
        path = self.imgs[index][0]
        # make a new tuple that includes original and the path
        tuple_with_path = (original_tuple + (path,))
        return tuple_with_path
```

Comment: Wait, I tell a lie. Yes, this prints the paths, but its printing all the paths, not the paths to the two images being compared for similarity.